# How to read summary result in R?

Tags: r, summary, poly

i fitted 3d scatter with lm, poly function.
But i couldnt write real equation from summary bucause some number...code is below.

```
Call:
lm(formula = z ~ poly(x, y, degree = 2))

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-5.224e-06 -2.527e-06  3.670e-08  2.674e-06  5.090e-06 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                8.901e-02  8.812e-08  1.010e+06   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, y, degree = 2)1.0  1.280e+00  2.930e-06  4.369e+05   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, y, degree = 2)2.0  2.219e-06  2.981e-06  7.440e-01    0.457    
poly(x, y, degree = 2)0.1  1.021e+00  2.928e-06  3.488e+05   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, y, degree = 2)1.1  1.469e+01  1.101e-04  1.334e+05   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, y, degree = 2)0.2 -1.558e-06  2.976e-06 -5.230e-01    0.601    
---
```

As you can see, there are wired number beside formula like "1.0", "2.0", "0.1", "1.1", "0.2"...
Anyone teach me?

Thank you.

Comment: You are fitting orthogonal polynomials. If you use `poly(x, y, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)` the "wired[sic!]" numbers are simply the exponents in sum(ai * x^d1i * y^d2i).

Comment: @Roland Thank you!